# Get and file content using web-api and consume it

Tags: c#, arrays, pdf, asp.net-web-api, file-get-contents

I'm trying to read PDF file, send its content (byte array wise) using httpget web api and then, in the client, create a new PDF file based on the get data from the web API.
However - when transferring the Byte[] data - it is being corrupted, meaning the size of the data changes.
this is my code:
This is the web api get method:

```
[Route("api/SystemSigner/Files/GetFile")]
public Byte[] GetFile()
{
    var path = @"<pdf path>.pdf";
    var dataBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    return dataBytes;
}
```

This is the web api "communicator" for consuming it (**it returns a task with a different size**):

```
public static async Task<Byte[]> GetFile()
{
    Byte[] retrunedTask = null;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApiUri"] + "/Files/GetFile");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/pdf"));
        retrunedTask = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(client.BaseAddress);
    }
    return retrunedTask;
}
```

This is the client consumer:

```
private async void CreateFile()
{
    Byte[] fileByteArray = await WebApiCommunicator.GetFile();
    string filePath = @"<File path to save the file>";
    File.WriteAllBytes(filePath , fileByteArray);
}
```

Comment: Try and set some debugging outputs where the web api communicator before returning the task like Debug.WriteLine(returnedTask.Length); and then also in your CreateFile() method before writting data and let us know the results.

Comment: The difference is as I mentioned - when consuming the web-api get request, after calling the 
await client.GetByteArrayAsync(client.BaseAddress);

Comment: That's a bit weird. Even when you use ReadAllBytes in the web api? You get x amount and on the client different amount? Try using WebClient instead of HttpClient just for testing.

Comment: Just a point of thinking, is there any encryption going on in the project you working on? Because normally when transferring files/packets or anything through network, the bytes should be encrypted and the client then decrypts them. So that might be the reason why you get different sizes due to the compression of the encryption.

Comment: Adding to @GiladReich's idea: What happens when you leave out the "application/pdf" header?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution for this problem: how to correctly get file content in web-api:
This is the web-api get method

```
  [Route("api/<Controller name>/Files/GetFile")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFile(string fileName)
    {
        string filePath = <Path to the wanted file on the server - same file system >
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        return response;
    }
```

This is the consuming code from the client:

```
 internal async static Task<Byte[]> GetFile(string fileName) 
{
        Byte[] returnedTask = null;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(string.Format(@"{0}{1}", <Web api URI>, "/Files/GetFile"));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            {
                uriBuilder.Query = string.Format("fileName={0}", fileName);
            }
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uriBuilder.ToString());
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/pdf"));
            returnedTask = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(client.BaseAddress);
        }
        return returnedTask;
    }
```

And this is the code on the client that consume the service, create and save file with the same content:

```
Byte[] fileByteArray = await <class name (static)>.GetFile(fileName);
        File.WriteAllBytes(<Local Path to save the file>, fileByteArray);
```